# Transitive closure of a non function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Having this relation R = {(1,1),(3,4),(2,2),(3,3)}, is the transitive closure itself? Trying to solve this, I know that this is only the union of an empty set with R, mainly because there's no pair starting with 4. Am I right?

Comment: Correct; the only *pairs* that you can "pair" are $(3,3)$ and $(3,4)$ and they produce $(3,4)$ which is already there.

Comment: This relation is already transitive.  The transitive closure of an already transitive relation is the relation itself.  This does not explicitly have anything to do with any pairs starting with or not starting with $4$.

Comment: The transitive closure is itself iff $R$ is transitive. Do you know how to check if $R$ is transitive?

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm not getting it. Given its definition if (a,b), (b,c) there must (a,c). I don't know why it has nothing to do with pairs starting with 4.

Comment: There exist transitive relations who contain pairs starting with $4$.  There exist transitive relations who do not contain pairs starting with $4$.  There exist nontransitive relations who contain pairs starting with $4$.  There exist nontransitive relations who do not contain pairs starting with $4$.  The statement "*mainly because there's no pair starting with 4*" that you made is woefully incomplete and inaccurate.